# GREP expression

Tags: replace, adobe, adobe-indesign, grep-indesign

I need help with a GREP expression to find and replace a variable group of words.
The sentence always starts with the same two words (Bold italicized) and always ends with a (colon), but the bit in the middle varies.
So I need to search for:

`Bold italicized` then any string of words then `:`

ie. starts with "Bold italicized", then any group of words, ends with ":"

For example:

```
Bold italicized May 6, 2010:
```

I will then apply some formatting to that text.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it, although this is a pretty simple one, so it seems like you should have been able to come up with this yourself, even as a beginner.

```
^Bold italicized.+?:
```

If you want to learn a little bit more about how to use GREP, I would recommend the [InDesign GREP reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/indesign/cs/using/WSFB3603CC-8D84-48d8-9F77-F3E0644CB0B6a.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot. In the end I used (bold italicized )( *.*\w*\d*)(:) and replaced with $2$3 which worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

The right tool do do this is not [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) but [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) :

**EXAMPLE** in a shell :

```
$ cat file.txt 
Bold italicized foo bar:
Bold italicized qux:
$ sed 's/^Bold italicized\(.*\):/do something with "\1"/g' file.txt
do something with " foo bar"
do something with " qux"
$
```

**NOTE**

- you will find tons of examples and documentation [here](http://sed.sourceforge.net/) or [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%5Bsed%5D&sitesearch=stackoverflow.com/questions)
- the basic `sed` substitution command is `s/regex/substitution/modifier`
- that use [regex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regex), I use `^` that means beginning of line, and `\( \)` to make a capture

Comment: I should have been more clear.  I'm not using this from the command line.  I'm using the GREP search and replace tool within Adobe Indesign.